# How to know if a vector on the right hand side

Tags: asp.net, math, vector, graph-theory, indoor-positioning-system

Let me first define my problem,

I am working on an indoor navigation problem. So I constructed a graph to simulate possible paths. I can easily calculate the shortest path with Dijkstra and draw it on a map. So far, so good.

But this is not enough,

I need to give instruction to user to navigate him.

For example:

```
"Turn Right"
"Turn Left"
"Go on from the left"
```

To give these kind of instructions I need to know which path is on the left and which path is on the right.

And here is what I have to solve this:

```
 1. A undirected weighted graph  
 2. The shortest path which contains vertices and edges   
 3. X and Y Coordinates of each vertices
```

By the way I will do this in .Net by using beacon technology.

Do you know how to separate left and right edges so I can give direction messages to user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to take the cross product of the vector representing the direction the player is facing/traveling and the vector representing direction you want the player to go in. Whether the player must turn left or right depends on whether the result's Y-coordinate is positive or negative, but which is which depends on the handedness of the coordinate system. I would just pick one and try it. You have a 50% of being right, and it's easy to reverse if you're wrong.

**Edit:**

[image: cross product image]

Here we see that *a×b* points up when *a* is to the right of *b*. However, we also see that *-a×b* points *down*. So, if *a* were pointing in the opposite direction—to the left—then the cross product would point down.

Comment: I couldn't get the relation between cross product and  left and right. Could you give a little detail ?

Comment: Added some further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product approach does not work in two dimensions. For this case you want to use the sign of the determinant of the matrix [A B], where A and B are your column vectors. A pseudo-code would be

c=sign(det([A B]))

Here, if c>0 is means that B is to the left. This will switch depending on the order of A and B in your matrix.